# Android Leakcanary Trace

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have integrated Leakcanary for the first time in my app, The trace is generated like the following. Can someone explain to me what does it mean?

```
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: In com.myboxman.app:1.0:79.
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity has leaked:
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.mListener
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * references helper.GPSTracker.mContext
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity instance
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 14MB.
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: e7c6cde6-bde2-4bc7-9aee-b5153bbed7cc
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Device: LGE google Nexus 4 occam
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.6-SNAPSHOT 05e6ee2
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5066ms, gc=211ms, heap dump=4524ms, analysis=50759ms
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Details:
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: * Instance of android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_STATUS_CHANGED = 2
02-16 12:06:21.272 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_DISABLED = 4
02-16 12:06:21.273 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_ENABLED = 3
02-16 12:06:21.273 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED = 1
02-16 12:06:21.273 14201-14490/com.myboxman.app D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[32]@316027281 (0x12d63191)
```

This would be more informative:

In com.myboxman.app:1.0:79.
* com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.mListener
* references helper.GPSTracker.mContext
* leaks com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity instance

- Retaining: 14MB.
- Reference Key: 7bf64f86-af48-4889-8a8c-517834d534a2
- Device: LGE google Nexus 4 occam
- Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.6-SNAPSHOT 05e6ee2
- Durations: watch=5141ms, gc=177ms, heap dump=6491ms, analysis=54624ms
- Details:
- Instance of android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport
  |   static TYPE_STATUS_CHANGED = 2
  |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_DISABLED = 4
  |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_ENABLED = 3
  |   static TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED = 1
  |   static $staticOverhead = byte[32]@316010897 (0x12d5f191)
  |   mListener = helper.GPSTracker@314613680 (0x12c09fb0)
  |   mListenerHandler = android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1@317068912 (0x12e61670)
  |   this$0 = android.location.LocationManager@315092368 (0x12c7ed90)
  |   mDescriptor = java.lang.String@1887341984 (0x707e8da0)
  |   mObject = -1201831376
  |   mOwner = android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport@317068816 (0x12e61610)
- Instance of helper.GPSTracker
  |   static MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 100
  |   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@316919809 (0x12e3d001)
  |   static MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 30000
  |   canGetLocation = true
  |   isGPSEnabled = true
  |   isNetworkEnabled = true
  |   latitude = 33.5890017
  |   listener = null
  |   location = android.location.Location@319020816 (0x1303df10)
  |   locationManager = android.location.LocationManager@315092368 (0x12c7ed90)
  |   longitude = 73.082723
  |   mContext = com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity@317117184 (0x12e6d300)
  |   mActivityManager = null
  |   mApplication = null
  |   mClassName = null
  |   mStartCompatibility = false
  |   mThread = null
  |   mToken = null
  |   mBase = null
- Instance of com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity
  |   static notificationType = null
  |   static $staticOverhead = byte[8]@317112321 (0x12e6c001)
  |   avloadingIndicatorView = com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView@318891648 (0x1301e680)
  |   client = null
  |   common = helper.Common@315091792 (0x12c7eb50)
  |   context = com.fretbay.myboxman.activities.SplashActivity@317117184 (0x12e6d300)
  |   delay = 5000
  |   exceptionCounter = 0
  |   gpsTimer = null
  |   gpsTracker = helper.GPSTracker@314613680 (0x12c09fb0)
  |   initialDelay = 10000
  |   isDisconnected = false
  |   isException = false
  |   layUserNote = android.widget.LinearLayout@318826496 (0x1300e800)
  |   marshMallowPermission = helper.MarshMallowPermission@314587200 (0x12c03840)
  |   networkTimer = null
  |   run = 0
  |   tvUserNote = helper.CustomFont@318828544 (0x1300f000)
  |   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14@314865280 (0x12c47680)
  |   mEatKeyUpEvent = false
  |   mResources = null
  |   mThemeId = 2131493020
  |   mCreated = true
  |   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController@317089376 (0x12e66660)
  |   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1@317087104 (0x12e65d80)
  |   mMediaController = null
  |   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
  |   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
  |   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat@317279296 (0x12e94c40)
  |   mReallyStopped = true
  |   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
  |   mResumed = false
  |   mRetaining = false
  |   mStopped = true
  |   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
  |   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
  |   mActionBar = null
  |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@315113600 (0x12c84080)
  |   mActivityTransitionState = android.app.ActivityTransitionState@317057600 (0x12e5ea40)
  |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap@317065888 (0x12e60aa0)
  |   mApplication = helper.MyApplication@315164864 (0x12c908c0)
  |   mCalled = true
  |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
  |   mChangingConfigurations = false
  |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
  |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@314999008 (0x12c680e0)
  |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
  |   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1@317089072 (0x12e66530)
  |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@317073056 (0x12e626a0)
  |   mDecor = null
  |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
  |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
  |   mDestroyed = true
  |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
  |   mEmbeddedID = null
  |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
  |   mEnterTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1894718984 (0x70ef1e08)
  |   mExitTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1894718984 (0x70ef1e08)
  |   mFinished = true
  |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl@317109184 (0x12e6b3c0)
  |   mHandler = android.os.Handler@317087072 (0x12e65d60)
  |   mIdent = 788657300
  |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@317089088 (0x12e66540)
  |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@315158784 (0x12c8f100)
  |   mIntent = android.content.Intent@315101632 (0x12c811c0)
  |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
  |   mLoaderManager = null
  |   mLoadersStarted = false
  |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@314855680 (0x12c45100)
  |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@317086976 (0x12e65d00)
  |   mManagedDialogs = null
  |   mMenuInflater = null
  |   mParent = null
  |   mReferrer = null
  |   mResultCode = 0
  |   mResultData = null
  |   mResumed = false
  |   mSearchManager = null
  |   mStartedActivity = false
  |   mStopped = true
  |   mTemporaryPause = false
  |   mTitle = java.lang.String@317182112 (0x12e7d0a0)
  |   mTitleColor = 0
  |   mTitleReady = true
  |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@314993664 (0x12c66c00)
  |   mTranslucentCallback = null
  |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1946976256 (0x740c8000)
  |   mVisibleBehind = false
  |   mVisibleFromClient = true
  |   mVisibleFromServer = true
  |   mVoiceInteractor = null
  |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@317186560 (0x12e7e200)
  |   mWindowAdded = true
  |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@317182880 (0x12e7d3a0)
  |   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater@317070352 (0x12e61c10)
  |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
  |   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@314603648 (0x12c07880)
  |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@317182912 (0x12e7d3c0)
  |   mThemeResource = 2131493020
  |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@317048448 (0x12e5c680)
- Excluded Refs:
  | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
  | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
  | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
  | Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
  | Field: android.animation.LayoutTransition$1.val$parent
  | Field: android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$1.this$0
  | Field: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
  | Field: android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
  | Field: android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.this$1
  | Field: android.media.MediaScannerConnection.mContext
  | Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
  | Field: android.media.AudioManager$1.this$0
  | Field: android.widget.Editor$Blink.this$0
  | Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
  | Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
  | Static field: android.text.TextLine.sCached
  | Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
  | Thread:main (always)
  | Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
  | Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
  | Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
  | Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
  | Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
  | Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)

Comment: Post the activity code

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar just edited

Comment: Can you paste your GPSTracker class?